# How to pass the session Id as part of request Header?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, httprequest

At present i am passing the session id in request URL like below to enter in to existing session from one of the client

```
    String urlStr = "/App1/MyApp.do;jsessionid=someSessionId";
    Properties reply = new Properties();
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.getInputStream()
```

What i want is passing the session Id in request header instead of passing it as url parameter.Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below:

```
ArrayList<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
            providers.add(new JacksonJsonProvider());

    WebClient client = WebClient.create(""/App1/MyApp.do", providers);

            client.header("jsessionid", someSessionId);
```